# How can I get additional data from one promise to another?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have one promise that relies on the return value of another promise. I'm successfully passing that value to the second promise, but there's additional data that's created in the first promise that I'd like to get into the second promise *somehow*.

Here's my code:

```
const getAlbumInfo = async (album, artist) => {
        let hostname = 'http://www.musicbrainz.org';
        let path = `/ws/2/release-group/?query=release:${album}%20AND%20artist:${artist}&fmt=json`;
        let res = await fetch(hostname + path);
        return res.json();
};


const getAlbumArt = async (albumInfo) => {
    let res = await fetch(`${albumInfo.url}`);
    return res.json();
};    


let artist = '', album = '';

getAlbumInfo(album, artist)
    .then((res) => {
        const metadata = {
            album: res['album'],
            artist: res['artist'],
            url: res['url']
        };

        return getAlbumArt(metadata);
    })
    .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);  // prints result from getAlbumArt

        // I also need the contents of metadata here
    })
    .catch(e => { console.error(e); });
```

So I'm getting album metadata in the first promise, which includes a URL, and then I'm running a fetch on that URL, which returns a second promise. The problem is that I need access to the album metadata in the second promise.

Since I'm returning/passing the metadata into the second promise, I tried using `Object.assign()` inside `getAlbumArt()` to combine the metadata and the fetch result, but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: You can return an object from first promise like this.

`return {album-art: getAlbumArt(metadata), meta: metadata}`

Comment: There is more like `Scope` issue with your `metadata`. Is any reason that you didn't put the variable to other methods level, like global?

Comment: why don't you use async-await for this instead of getAlbumInfo() -> then getAlbumArt() -> then do something. Plus if you wish to do in promise way, you can declare metadata variable on top, assign its value after getAlbumInfo() and then use it after getAlbumArt().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this, you could use `await`:

```
const getAlbumInfo = async(album, artist) => {
  let hostname = 'http://www.musicbrainz.org';
  let path = `/ws/2/release-group/?query=release:${album}%20AND%20artist:${artist}&fmt=json`;
  let res = await fetch(hostname + path);
  return res.json();
};


const getAlbumArt = async(albumInfo) => {
  let res = await fetch(`${albumInfo.url}`);
  return res.json();
};


let artist = '',
  album = '';

const getAll = async() => {
  const res1 = await getAlbumInfo(album, artist);
  const metadata = {
    album: res['album'],
    artist: res['artist'],
    url: res['url']
  };
  const res2 = await getAlbumArt(metadata);

  // here you have access to both responses (res1 and res2) and the created metadata object.
}
```

If you use this, you should wrap the calls in `try..catch..`.

Another option will be to pass the metadata from the second promise along with the response:

```
const getAlbumInfo = async(album, artist) => {
  let hostname = 'http://www.musicbrainz.org';
  let path = `/ws/2/release-group/?query=release:${album}%20AND%20artist:${artist}&fmt=json`;
  let res = await fetch(hostname + path);
  return res.json();
};


const getAlbumArt = async(albumInfo) => {
  let res = await fetch(`${albumInfo.url}`);
  res = await res.json();
  return {
    res,
    albumInfo
  };
};


let artist = '',
  album = '';

getAlbumInfo(album, artist)
  .then((res) => {
    const metadata = {
      album: res['album'],
      artist: res['artist'],
      url: res['url']
    };

    return getAlbumArt(metadata);
  })
  .then((o) => {
    console.log(o.res, o.albumInfo);
  })
  .catch(e => {
    console.error(e);
  });
```

And a third option will be to resolve the second promise inside the first promise's callback function:

```
getAlbumInfo(album, artist)
  .then((res) => {
    const metadata = {
      album: res['album'],
      artist: res['artist'],
      url: res['url']
    };

    getAlbumArt(metadata)
      .then(res2 => {
        // here you can access res, res2 and metadata
      })
      .catch(..);
  })
  .catch(..);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you could use `async/await`, we could solve the problem using this too. It's better to consistent using `async/await` instead of mix it with Promise.

To do that, we need [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

```js
(async () => { // define IIFE
  try { // try-catch to ensure error is catched
    const res = await getAlbumInfo(album, artist);

    const metadata = {
      album: res["album"],
      artist: res["artist"],
      url: res["url"]
    };

    const res2 = await getAlbumArt(metadata);

    console.log(res2);
    console.log(metadata);

  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
})();
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

`await` for the second promise and then return both to the next `.then` block. Use deconstruct for a simpler use case:

```
getAlbumInfo(album, artist)
    .then(async ({album, artist, url}) => {
        const metadata = {album, artist, url};
        const arts = await getAlbumArt(metadata);

        return {arts, metadata};
    })
    .then(({arts, metadata}) => {
        // You have both here 
    })
    .catch(console.log);
```

Alternatively, this entire action can be inside an `async` function:

```
const getAlbum = async (album, artist) => {
  const info = await getAlbumInfo(album, artist);
  const metadata = {
    album: info.album,
    artist: info.artist,
    url: info.url,
  };
  const arts = await getAlbumArt(metadata);

  // everything is available;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use then in the inner promise and return any format of data u want frm there.

```
getAlbumInfo(album, artist)
.then((res) => {
    const metadata = {
        album: res['album'],
        artist: res['artist'],
        url: res['url']
    };

    return getAlbumArt(metadata).then(responseArt => {
       return {
           innerPromise: responseArt,
           outerPromise: metadata
       };
    });
})
.then((res) => {
    console.log(res);  // Now u have both here

    // I also need the contents of metadata here
})
.catch(e => { console.error(e); });
```